# Ejecutar una sentencia asíncrona solo después del éxito de la primera sentencia asíncrona

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Partiendo de las siguientes sentencias asíncronas:

```java
mfirestorefacultades.collection("Facultades").document(gmidfacultad).update(mapfacultadescarpetas);

mfirestorefacultadessedes.collection("Facultades").whereEqualTo("idsede", gmidsede).whereEqualTo("cajatotalfacultad", "S").
get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
        if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
            mapsedescarpetas.put("cajasede", "E");
        } else {
            mapsedescarpetas.put("cajasede", "S");
        }
        mfirestoresedes.collection("Sedes").document(gmidsede).update(mapsedescarpetas);
    }
});
```

Me gustaría cambiar el flujo de ejecución de modo que la lógica de la segunda sentencia se ejecute sólo en el caso de que esta primera sentencia se realice con éxito:

```java
mfirestorefacultades.collection("Facultades")
    .document(gmidfacultad)
    .update(mapfacultadescarpetas);
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un flujo de control de las tareas asincrónicas de manera que la segunda tarea se ejecute sólo en el caso de que la primera se realice sin errores. Es lo que la documentación de Firebase denomina una función de ["completion callback"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback)

Para que la segunda sentencia se ejecute solo después de que la primera se complete con éxito, puedes utilizar una estructura de `addOnSuccessListener` para la primera sentencia y, dentro de ella, ejecutar la segunda instrucción.

```java
mfirestorefacultades.collection("Facultades").document(gmidfacultad)
        .update(mapfacultadescarpetas)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                mfirestorefacultadessedes.collection("Facultades")
                        .whereEqualTo("idsede", gmidsede)
                        .whereEqualTo("cajatotalfacultad", "S")
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful() && !task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                                    mapsedescarpetas.put("cajasede", "S");
                                    mfirestoresedes.collection("Sedes")
                                            .document(gmidsede)
                                            .update(mapsedescarpetas);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

`onSuccessListener` es una [interfaz](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/OnSuccessListener) que incorpora el [método](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/OnSuccessListener.html#onSuccess(ResultT)) `onSuccess`, el cual es invocado cuando una tarea o `Task` es completada con éxito para que el código dentro de su bloque sea ejecutado.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.